posgresql serial number from same id
i need to get the same row number if the values get in column plan No



Plan No.
item ID




T190931
201022


T190931
220933


T190932
289338


T190933
374882


T190936
093022


T190936
266679


T190936
346762


T190936
327392



The expected result is:



Plan No.
item ID
rownum




T190931
201022
1


T190931
220933
2


T190932
289338
1


T190933
374882
1


T190936
093022
1


T190936
266679
2


T190936
346762
3


T190936
327392
4




So, you will likely write ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY plan_number). Do you have a question? "I need" isn't one.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

select *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Plan_No) as rownum from T;

More details check the sample code: https://dbfiddle.uk/HzHCTjb2
